# nginx: limit access to 1 request at a time / zero size shared memory zone

Tags: nginx

I want to limit an admin-page to only 1 request at a time (as in: only 1 person at a time can look at that page). That page can be reached via a port > http://admin.url.com:8010. If I understand correctly from documentation, i need to specify `limit_conn_zone` in the nginx config http block, and `limit_conn` in the relevant server block.

This is a simplified version of my nginx.conf file:

```
http {

    limit_conn_zone $server_name zone=server:10m;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        ...
    }


    server {
        listen 8010;
        server_name admin.url.com;
        limit_conn servers 1;
    }
}
```

There are several more server blocks in this config file.

After putting in those two lines of code, and restarting nginx I get the following error message:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] zero size shared memory zone "servers"
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is the problem that I now have to define `limit_conn` within every server block?

Comment: You define zone `server` and use `servers`

Comment: Also "1 request at a time" is completely irrelevant to "1 person at a time".

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyTen, didn't see that missing 's'. Now i don't get the error anymore, but i still seem to be able to access the page multiple times (though coming from the same IP).

Answer (score 0):

If you want limit on the `$server_name` variable you MUST set the name in the servers section. For example:

```
server {
 server_name _;
 listen       80 default_server;
 ...
```

Even the Nginx documentation miss this hint, see https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-http/